# Maven, exclude resources from jar and add them in resulting war

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a multi-module maven project like the following

```
<modules>
  <module>mod1</module>
  <module>jarMod</module>
  <module>warMod</module>
</modules>
```

In the end, everything is assembled in warMod war archive through maven dependencies and war packaging. 
In jarMod I have property files under /resources, which I want to exclude from jar and have them in resulting war (so when app is deployed, I can modify those files).

I've managed to exclude files from jar, as for now, and add path to them to class-path in jar manifest. Remaining problem is, how do I add them in resulting war file (like in WEB-INF) and still access them from classes in jar? Right now it's done through 'getResourceAsStream()'

Comment: Try moving the property files to their own jar.  Use provided scope in the jarMod pom and no scope param in the warMod pom (for the new properties jar)

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

When building the war you could copy the property file under the WEB-INF/classes to place it on the classpath (just as it would've been in the jar)

Comment: That is the point of my question, how do I do that? I know about resources plugin, but I don't think it can work with resources from other module